# Is there a good way to wrap an existing Python based web application to require a login?

Tags: authentication, apache, open-source

I'm in the process of installing an open-source Python based web application to an internal server here at work.  The existing code is open - it doesn't require a login to view it - but one of the requirements is that users have to be approved before they can see anything.

Is there a good way (using Apache configuration files for example, but any method would be great) to wrap the application so that any access requires a login?  I would like to avoid modifying the open-source code (a maintenance nightmare every time a new release comes out).

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache supports [Authentication, Authorization and Access Control](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/auth.html).

It is a detailed process, and summarising it here would not do it justice. I refer you to the link provided,